Using VS Code can't debug the godot extension in Windows C++
Godot Version
4.2.1
Question
I am using 4.2.1 stable for Windows. In VC Code I set up the project. Everything is working fine and I able to execute the scene from VC Code. The problem is I can't hit the breakpoint when trying to debug
using godot-cpp 4.2 branch, and Godot 4.2.1 stable.
This is my VC Code configurations
{   
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "name": "Debug",            
            "program": "c:\\dev\\my\\godot\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64_console.exe",
            "args": ["--path","c:\\dev\\my\\godot\\godotcpp\\test4\\demo"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

{
     
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "scons.exe -j4  target=template_debug  debug_symbols=yes ",
        }
    ]
}

scones command : scons.exe -j4  target=template_debug  debug_symbols=yes

What am I missing here ?

What debugger have you linked/are you using?

using visual studio 2022
